# Joomla High availability environment on AWS - Shifting sessions

Tags: joomla, high-availability

I am using joomla-2.5 and I want to deploy it on AWS.
In order to create a High Availability environment, I am using Load balancer and need to shift sessions from ec2 instances to Database. I got this info from [This Link](http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/php/high-availability-joomla-wordpress-load-balance-persistant-php-database-sessions/)

Please suggest how to do this session shifting.

Comment: The database is set by default as the session handler in Joomla. Can you describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: Did you got the point with "database is set by default as the session handler in Joomla"? So your session is already stored in the database. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Oh yes I got it. I was concerned about sessions handling.